# ExecuteStoreQuery with TVP parameters

Tags: entity-framework-4, executestorequery

I have a stored procedure in my database that takes a table value parameter, a list of IdTable objects which contain a single integer Id column.

I have an entity model for the database and want to do the following...

```
ProjectEntities projectEntities = new ProjectEntities ();

DataTable stationIds = new DataTable();
stationIds.Columns.Add("Id");
stationIds.Rows.Add(1);
stationIds.Rows.Add(2);

SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@stationIds",stationIds);
parameter.TypeName = "IdTable";

var parameters = new object[] {parameter};

var results = projectEntities .ExecuteStoreQuery<ProjectSummary>("exec ProjectSummary", parameters);

var count = results.Count();
```

This runs and returns no results, when it should return a bunch of ProjectSummary entities.

When I profile this in SQL Profiler, I get the following

```
declare @p3 IdTable
insert into @p3 values(N'1')
insert into @p3 values(N'2')

exec sp_executesql N'exec ProjectSummary',N'@stationIds [IdTable] READONLY',@stationIds=@p3
```

If I declare the stored procedure to be

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProjectSummary]
    @stationIds  [dbo].[IdTable] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT * FROM @stationIds
...
```

Then I get not results back, it looks like the TVP parameter is coming through empty.

Where as if I manually execute

```
declare @p3 IdTable
insert into @p3 values(N'1')
insert into @p3 values(N'2')

EXEC    [ProjectSummary]
        @stationIds = @p3

GO
```

I get the values 1 and 2 returned from the SELECT query.

So, it looks like I want to use EXEC rather than SP_EXECUTESQL when I run ExecuteStoreCommand. Given the code example above, how on earth do I do that?

Comment: How did you add your user-defined table type IdType to EF? I thought doing that is not possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the ExecuteStoreQuery call was incorrect, it should be

```
SqlParameter stations = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "p0", Value = ids, TypeName = "[dbo].[IdTable]", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured };

var parameters = new object[] { stations };

var results = projectEntities.ExecuteStoreQuery<ProjectSummary>("exec ProjectSummary @p0", parameters);
```

So I needed to name parameter and add the @p0 to the exec command.